# Is it possible to cancel a spin dash?

Tags: sonic-mania

Sometimes during a level, I'll notice a hidden area or powerup I want to go back and explore, but I've already started revving up a spindash towards the next area.

Is there any way to cancel a spindash after revving it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research and trying this out for myself, it is safe to say that there is no key that you can press to cancel a spin dash.

But, if there is a convenience, you can touch or land on a moving block, and your spin dash will immediately stop.